# ShareActionProvider without any action bar in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-actionbar

I do not want an action bar in my app and still want to have that share button that is provided by the action bar.

This is done when action bar is there.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    ShareActionProvider provider = (ShareActionProvider)
    menu.findItem(R.id.menu_share).getActionProvider();

    if (provider != null) {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "hi");
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        provider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
    }

    return true;
}
```

And the menu.xml is kept in menu folder.

Where as I want a share button of my own in my xml where other layouts are also defined.

any help?

Comment: `ShareActionProvider` won't work without `ActionBar`. But you should get some ideas by looking at it's [implementation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/ShareActionProvider.java)

Answer (score 9):

You don't need an Action Bar to share content.  In fact, even with an Action Bar, most apps don't use the `ShareActionProvider` because visually designers hate it and it doesn't support a lot of the latest share features on a users device (like direct sharing to contacts).  Instead you should use `Intent.createChooser` to create a more robust share dialog.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```

http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html

An even better way to Share from anywhere in your app is to use `ShareCompat`. Here is a quick example:

```
ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
           .setType("text/plain")
           .setText("I'm sharing!")
           .startChooser();
```

Other examples can be found here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/SharingSupport.java

Answer (score 5):

Use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` to find the apps that know how to handle the `ACTION_SEND` `Intent` that you want to invoke. Display the resulting list however you would like. When the user makes a selection, create a equivalent `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`, where you specify the `ComponentName` of the particular activity that the user chose, and call `startActivity()`.

Comment: Can you help me out more with this? As in if the component names are not known then?
Or link to any article will be helpful.

Comment: @user2607444: "As in if the component names are not known then?" -- yes, they are, as that was the point behind the first two sentences of my answer. For example, here is a "launcher" that performs a similar operation, but for `ACTION_MAIN`/`CATEGORY_HOME`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Introspection/Launchalot

Answer (score 1):

Use an Intent with ACTION_SEND.  For example, when a button is clicked you could:

```
Intent It = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
It.setType("text/plain");
It.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"your_text_to_share");
YourActivity.this.startActivity(It);
```

Comment: thanks Andrew: i was using a mobile phone (it wasn't mine and also it wasn't a "smart enough" phone :-) to write the code correctly)